# Determine if MailItem is open in Compose or Read mode

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2007

Is there some way that I can determine if a `MailItem` is being opened in a `ReadMail view` (not sure about the terminology here) or in a `Compose view`. That is, am I opening a mail that has been sent to me, or am I opening a mail to send to someone.

I've checked the [MailItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208402%28office.12%29.aspx) and the [Inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208374%28office.12%29.aspx) objects but can't find anything of relevance. Unfortunately I don't know how to access specific Properties (I've seen some `GetProperty()` method somewhere) so I don't know if I could access it via that..

I was hoping that there would be something I could do like:

```
// where OutlookApp is my Outlok Application
Outlook.Inspector inspector = OutlookApp.ActiveInspector();
Outlook.MailItem item = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
if (item.IsOpenInComposeView)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Does the property `Caption` of the `Inspector` not give any clues?

Comment: I checked, it states "Message" for both

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`_MailItem.Sent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.sent.aspx) will be true when the message is in **Read** mode, and false when the message is in **Compose** mode.

Comment: Wont will work if the message is a reply, only if is a new mail messagem

Comment: Finally! Any documentation you can point us to for similar issues? I've been searching way too long for this..